# python paramiko giving error "Permission denied [Errno 13]" on windows server on using sftp

Tags: python, windows, sftp, paramiko

trying to download some files from windows server using sftp in paramiko. get method is:

```
def get(self, remotepath, localpath = None):
    """Copies a file between the remote host and the local host."""
    if not localpath:
        localpath = os.path.split(remotepath)[1]
    self._sftp_connect()
    self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
```

On running the script as 
`sshObj.get('C:\\my_file.txt', 'D:\\python\\')`, it throws the error :

```
 File "C:\Py34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 806, in _convert_status
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)`PermissionError: [Errno 13] **Permission denied**`
```

I have given all the permissions to the folder. 
also shared it with other users. But still the error is there. Any leads if anyone has faced this before will be helpful.

Note: I installed freesshd to make my localbox an ssh server.

Comment: With SFTP you needs to use forward slashes in remote path (even when connected to Windows server). Also find out what syntax of paths the SFTP server use to refers to drives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. Tried with `sshObj.get(r'C:\my_file.txt', r'D:\python\my_file.txt')` but it din't help..still the same error.. Also Martin, `what syntax of paths the SFTP server use to refers to drives` => how to check this? Probably the syntax `E:/` should be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks All!
Finally I found the answer. 
It was because of the format of the filepaths.

On trying `sshObj.get("/remote_file.txt","C:/tmp/local_file.txt")` it succeded without any error.

Download the tool winSCP, it has a good GUI which will help you understand the format of file paths properly.

Also check your base SFTP folder on the remote machine because in my case the error was thrown because `remote_file.txt` was not located at the root sftp folder(which can be configured manually) on the remote box.

Answer (score 18):

It is not about the path naming convention.
In the local path, you did not mention the file name, you have just mentioned the directory to save the file.
Use:
`sshObj.get('C:\\my_file.txt', 'D:\\python\\my_file.txt')`
instead of
`sshObj.get('C:\\my_file.txt', 'D:\\python\\')`

Comment: this fixed my problem

Comment: Great this also fixed my problem!

Comment: Yes, the file name is missing!. it is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you have setup freesshd, the file you want to get should be located within the home directory, where your freesshd serves. I imagine the remote path should be something like `/path/to/file`.

According to your code snippet, you want to get file from `c:\\my_file.txt`. There are at least two problems:

1. POSIX-like file system use `/` and there is no drive path. `C:\` will never work.
2. Is `C:\` accessible to your freessdh? I have doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I received the error while running the `put` function, the error was caused by the file already existing in the SFTP server.
You better check if the file exists with `sftp.listdir(path)`, before sending the file